# Calculating the total sum of inversion count for all subarrays

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, complexity

My approach was to visit all inversion count pair and count how many subarrays these pair contribute. Visiting every pair requires \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ time, but I want an optimized version of this, something like \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$.

Can I do something with the Fenwick tree?
[Inversion in an array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/)
[Fenwick tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree-2/)

e.g.  if `arr = [1,3,4,2]` , then total inversion count for all subarrays = `5`.

```
number = int(input("Input number := "))
main_list = list(map(int,input().split()))
answer = 0
for i in range(number):
    for j in range(number):
        if i<j and main_list[i]>main_list[j]:
            k = (i+1) * (number-j)
            answer += k
print(answer)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is this a task you have chosen for yourself or is this from a programming course or challenge? If so, please include a link to the original problem description and also include it in an abbreviated from directly in your question.

Comment: My college senior gave me the problem.

Comment: Since you are only concerned with `i < j` why not put j in `range(i + 1, n)`?

Comment: yeah, I'll do that, but still, the time complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: You need to learn the naming convention.https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: This question should include a brief description of what _inversion_ and _Fenwick tree_ mean in this context, as well as links for both. More context will get you a more meaningful review.

Comment: Your original code works.  The edit by @brijeshkalkani changed `n` to `number` in several places, but `k = (i+1) * (n-j)` remained unchanged.  It also changed `l` to `main_list`, but didn't change all occurrences, and mistyped one occurrence as `mail_list`.  Moreover, it changed spacing (a PEP review comment) and added a prompt to an `input()` that never existed. The edit should never have been approved.

Comment: now it should work

Comment: @AJNeufeld I'm sorry about that. Can you suggest me any way to do this stuff efficiently?

Comment: No need to apologize.  Yes, you approved the edit, but you're new here, so easily forgiven.  @brijeshkalkani is to blame for the low-quality edit, but they are also relatively new here and can be forgiven.  "Community" is to blame for the rubber-stamp approval.  I can give you a more efficient, code-golfed, one-line solution `answer = sum(i*j for i, di in enumerate(main_list[:-1], 1) for j, dj in enumerate(main_list[:i-1:-1], 1) if di > dj)` but that doesn't make use of a _Fenwick tree_, which will require more thought.

Comment: but the worst-case complexity is still O(n^2) here. In the problem length of array <=10^5. The worst-case complexity of O(nlogn) is expected.